# TSLINT - Regra para variável privada

Tags: typescript

Existe alguma regra no tslint para definir que uma variável privada precisa ter `_` (underline) antes do nome?

Exemplo: `private _router: Router,`

Comment: Talvez isso possa te ajudar: http://crockford.com/javascript/, tem um topico Private Members in JavaScript

Comment: Opa, não entendi como isso pode me ajudar. Pode ser mais claro?

Comment: Pode ser que eu tenha entendido errado, apesar de estar bem simples a pergunta, perdão...

Comment: Sem problemas. Eu preciso de alguma regra do lint, para validar e informar que uma variável private tem que ter _ antes do nome.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que essa regra ainda não foi implementada no `tslint`. Pelo que pesquisei, existe uma issue aberta para o repositório no GitHub. Assim, sugiro que você acompanhe-a:

https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/1489

Espero ter ajudado!